# Why sealed classes are not allowed to be generic type constraints?

Tags: c#, generics

I just wanted to know why sealed classes are not allowed to be generic type constraints?

Let's suppose i have a simple code snippet in c# as bellow

```
 public sealed class Base
{
    public Base() { }
}

public class Derived<T>
        where T : Base
{
    public Derived() { }
}
```

When i am instantiating the Derivedclass i am getting **'Base' is not a valid constraint. A type used as a constraint must be an interface, a non-sealed class or a type parameter.**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because then there's no point in it being generic. `T` could *only* be `Base`, so you might as well make it a non-generic type to start with.

Why would you *want* `Derived` to be generic here? Why would you *want* a type called `Base` (implying that it should be a base type) to be sealed?

Comment: My guess is that he's generating code. It's not like the code generator is going to know that somebody stuck a `sealed` on the class.

Comment: And of course by similar logic you cannot use "object" as a constraint, for the opposite reason; T is already going to be convertible to object because only types that are convertible to object may be used as type arguments, so the constraint would be redundant.

Comment: @EricLippert Even though it has no functional benefit. It does have a maintenance benefit because you can much easier swap out a generic constraint type than replacing all instances of the sealed class within a new type. Albeit a small benefit I don't see why one would enforce a non-sealed generic type.

Answer (score 2):

Because T will never have child classes! There's no point to have such kind of generic.

Comment: Actually, T could have child classes if it was unsealed later.  Though if that happened, the existing code would continue to work as written, so this situation is not an issue.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler doesn't want to go through the trouble of making something generic if there's only one class it can ever be.  Note that one can use a sealed class as a generic constraint if the sealed class is passed as a type parameter.  For example, if one has a class

```
Class Foo(Of T, U As T)
```

one may create an instance of that class where both generic type parameters are the same sealed type, since one could also create instances where the type parameters refer to different types.

Answer (score 0):

`T` cant be anything else but `Base`. So, whats the point making it Generic ?